# What can I do with a dead mouse, an inflatable bag and a charged battery?

Tags: stick-it-to-the-man

I'm currently in chapter 6, the asylum. I completed every action that is marked as a question mark on the map. I've got a dead mouse, an inflatable bag and a charged battery in my inventory, but I've got no idea what to do next.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Easy, you use the dead mouse attached to the battery to build a Meca-Mouse. Use the Meca-Mouse to sneak into any Hellium Storage, inflate the bag with the Hellium and attach it on the back of the mouse. use the Flying Meca-Mouse to conquer the world. Easy game.

Comment: That title though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one took me a while to figure out.

You need to use the dead mouse to lure the sewing girl (the one who was sewing a dead cat) to the whale, so she can sew the whale. After that, everything else becomes fairly obvious.

Place the inflatable bag on top of the whale, so the hyperventilating guy can inflate the whale and give the charged battery to the whaler guy.